# breeze: client-side model with navigationProperty is giving error

Tags: breeze

When calling addEntityType for `ResourceUnavailabilities`, I get the error:  `error configuring an instance of 'NavigationProperty'. The 'entityTypeName' parameter  must be a 'string'`

I don't get it. I've looked at the [tutorial](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) on breeze's website, and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

client-side model:

```
       metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: 'Unavailability',
            namespace: 'ecdt',
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: DT.Guid, isPartOfKey: true },
                startDate: { dataType: DT.DateTimeOffset },
                endDate: { dataType: DT.DateTimeOffset },
                isDayOff: { dataType: DT.Boolean }
            }
        });

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Unavailability', null, null);

        metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: 'ResourceUnavailabilities',
            namespace: 'ecdt',
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: DT.Guid, isPartOfKey: true },
                resourceId: { dataType: DT.Int32 },
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                unavailabilities: { dataType: 'Unavailability', hasMany: true }
            }
        });

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('ResourceUnavailabilities', null, null);
```

Apart from that everthing works fine. I can create `Unavailability` entities and also `ResourceUnavailabilities` entities (as long as I remove the navigation property...)

Also, in the tutorial, you use the `name`property instead of `shortname`. If I do that, I get an error 
`Error configuring an instance of 'EntityType'. Unknown property: 'name'`. Is the sample out-of-date ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's solved. The correct mapping is:

```
  metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: 'Unavailability',
            namespace: 'ecdt',
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: DT.Guid, isPartOfKey: true },
                startDate: { dataType: DT.DateTimeOffset },
                endDate: { dataType: DT.DateTimeOffset },
                isDayOff: { dataType: DT.Boolean }
            },

            navigationProperties: {
                unavailabilities: { entityTypeName: 'ResourceUnavailabilities', isScalar: true, associationName: "test" }
            }
        });

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Unavailability', null, null);

        metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: 'ResourceUnavailabilities',
            namespace: 'ecdt',
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: DT.Guid, isPartOfKey: true },
                resourceId: { dataType: DT.Int32 },
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                unavailabilities: { entityTypeName: 'Unavailability', isScalar: false, associationName: "test" }
            }
        });
```

Looks like the breeze document is not exactly up-to-date.

Comment: Which document? I'll update it if you give me a link.

Comment: the link is in my first post (tutorial): here it is again: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand

Comment: What part is incorrect? This page states that it uses the "breeze.metadata-helper.js" component to make creating metadata easier. Maybe you didn't see that or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: the sample code is incorrect. Like I said in my first post, this code does not work: `unavailabilities: { dataType: 'Unavailability', hasMany: true }`

Comment: @Sam - I don't know why you say the documentation is incorrect. The code there is lifted direct from working tests. To make this even more clear, I've ported it into a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/A1vPWiMtGJy35MTzPuSb/preview) so you can run it live and explore it with your own tests.

Comment: I think the problem in your original code is the property **`dataType`**. That is NOT valid for describing a `navigationProperty` and I cannot find anything on the ["Metadata By Hand"](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) documentation page that says otherwise.  That's because a navigation refers to an `EntityType`, not some garden-variety datatype. The Breeze API word is `entityTypeName` as you discovered. The Metadata-Helper abbreviation/alias is `type`. See the metadata for `Person.speakerSessions` for an example.